# How to stop expired client secret breaking single sign on (SSO) in .net integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, single-sign-on, .net-6.0

I've built a few .NET apps in both .NET core and .NET framework now that use single sign-on (SSO) with Microsoft as an authentication provider, and my company are increasingly rolling this out into older systems too.

The official documentation for adding [Microsoft Account external login setup with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0) gives the following code snippet:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
{
    microsoftOptions.ClientId = configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
    microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
});
```

The problem with this is that client secrets [can now no longer be set to never expire](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/client-secret-expiration-now-limited-to-a-maximum-of-two-years/). I get why this is and that's all fine - the problem this now presents me with is, that at some point the SSO for my .NET APP is just going to stop working without any warning.

Now, yes I could put something in the company calendar or something to go and create a new secret and then go and update all the key stores or settings files with the new keys, but this is really inefficient and asking for trouble. Surely Microsoft can't be expecting us to build stuff with such an obvious point of failure?

Does anyone know how to implement Microsoft SSO without the use of client secrets (maybe a certificate or Managed identity??) so that my apps don't suddenly all break overnight one day?

Comment: What's asking for trouble is never rotating security keys.

Comment: Yes, and I'm also happy to do that, but you'd want that to happen auto-magically really e.g. the app client secret auto gets refreshed and the updated value saved in Azure KeyVault but I'm not sure if that's possible either.....